# Remove consistently dependent smaller integers

Tags: code-golf, array

Consider this nested array

`[[1,2,4],[1,2,3],[2,3]]`

In each subarray in which 1 appears, a 2 appears. You might say that 1's presence is dependent on 2's presence.
The converse is not true, as 2 appears in a subarray without 1.
Additionally, 3 is dependent on 2, and 4 is dependent on 1 and 2.

### Task

Given a list of lists of positive integers (in whatever I/O form is most convenient for you) remove only the integers which are dependent on integers larger than themselves. In other words, for every integer A that is dependent on an integer B, and B>A, remove A.

### You may assume:

Positive integers only

Input will not be nested further than one level, as in the example above

No integer will appear more than once in a given subarray

Subarrays will be sorted (increasing or decreasing, whichever is more convenient as long as you state in your answer)

No empty arrays anywhere in input

### Examples:

```
in: [[1,2,4],[1,2,3],[2,3]]
out: [[2,4],[2,3],[2,3]]
in: [[3,4],[5,6]]
out: [[4],[6]]
in: [[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4]]
out: [[3],[3,4],[3,4]]
in: [[1]]
out: [[1]]
in: [[2,12],[2,13],[2,14]]
out: [[2,12],[2,13],[2,14]]
```

Shortest code wins :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <sup><s>104</s></sup> 93 bytes

```
lambda i:[[x for x in a if~-any(x<c>0<all(c in d for d in i if x in d)for c in a)]for a in i]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY5NCsIwEEb3nmKWCaRgWhWR6kViFrEhGKhpKRHajRdxUxDFK3kb81eUrubNfG-Yub_awZ4bMz7U_vi8WpVtP7wWl5MUoHeM9aCaDnrQBtxA3TJhBtSX1WFZirpGlQ9kcKRH7ZxoS-yHIReYexZB4OnIu-20sUghxiiBnMCKE0hYeAyVY7z4iUWy1gQ2s-hvMWFyJ5zps95ZNE86nc7TsBX_HcdYvw)

Stupid naïve iterative solution which I'm really not happy with. A recursive solution will be shorter.

-11 bytes thanks to a hint from xnor.

```
for a in z for b in a for c in b for d in c for e in d for f in e for g in f for h in g for i in h for j in i for k in j for l in j for m in l for n in m for o in n for p in o for q in p for r in q for s in r for t in s for u in t for v in u for w in v for x in w for y in x for z in y please kill me why is python's syntax so whitespace and keyword heavy
```

Comment: I think the mess of loops could be simplified a little by noting that the candidate `c`'s that `x` might depend on are restricted to those also in `a` along with `x`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 21 bytes

```
ＩＥθΦι⬤ι∨¬›νλ⊙θ‹№πν№πλ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzexQKNQR8EtM6cktUgjU0fBMScHRPkXafjll2i4F6UmgiTydBRyNDWBsnmVIOU@qcXFGs75pUBTCnQU8oAScA5QGRRY//8fHR1tqGOkYxyrA6F1TIAsCB0b@1@3LAcA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
  θ                     Input array
 Ｅ                      Map over subarrays
    ι                   Current subarray
   Φ                    Filtered where
      ι                 Current subarray
     ⬤                  All elements satisfy
          ν             Innermost element
        ¬›              Not greater than
           λ            Inner element
       ∨                Logical Or
             θ          Input array
            ⊙           Any subarray satisfies
               №        Count of
                 ν      Innermost element
                π       In innermost subarray
              ‹         Is less than
                  №     Count of
                    λ   Inner element
                   π    In innermost subarray
Ｉ                       Cast to string
                        Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ċƇf/>Ƈ⁹ȧ
çⱮFḟ@Ɱ
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of lists of strictly positive integers that yields a list of lists of strictly positive integers.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9I97H2NH27Y@2PGneeWM51ePmjjevcHu6Y7wCk/x9uf9S05uikhztnAOnI//@jo6MNdYx0TGJ1wLQxkAaRsVw60dHGYGFTHTMIFyYPpsFSEBoiCaGMdAyNwBKGEJMMQdKxAA)** (The footer calls the Link for each and formats the output)

#### How?

```
ċƇf/>Ƈ⁹ȧ - Helper Link: list of lists, A; integer, I
 Ƈ       - filter keep those lists in A for which:
ċ        -   count occurrences of I - truthy if the list contains I
   /     - reduce this list of lists that contain I by:
  f      -   filter keep
             - gets us a list of those values appearing in all of them
      ⁹  - use I as the right argument of:
     Ƈ   -   filter keep those for which:
    >    -     greater than I?
       ȧ - logical AND I (non-vectorising)
             - i.e. I if it is a consistently dependent smaller integer, else 0

çⱮFḟ@Ɱ - Link: list of lists, A
  F    - flatten A
 Ɱ     - map across each integer I in that with:
ç      -   call the Helper Link as a dyad - f(A, I)
     Ɱ - map across each list in A with:
    @  -   with swapped arguments:
   ḟ   -     filter discard
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>167</s> <s>163</s> <s>159</s> <s>157</s> 147 bytes

Or **[R](https://www.r-project.org/)>= 4.1, 126 bytes** by replacing three `function` occurrences with `\`s.

*Edit: -2 bytes thanks to [@Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe) and -10 bytes thanks to [@Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen).*

```r
function(x,b=combn(c(0,sort(unique(unlist(x)))),2))lapply(x,setdiff,b[1,apply(b,2,function(y,`+`=function(k)sapply(x,match,x=y[k],0))all(!+1|+2))])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU9BboMwELz3FTSnXbGHrElySMRLCFLAjRUUx6TBSCD179TGqS@uD7Nja2fG81pUuajRSNv1BiZqS9k/WgMStjT0Lwuj6b7Hqxu6GyxM6A4JRN08n3p2guFqvzqlqK2YwltLgqLjTJf8UsbrHYc/4aOx8kZTOVf3mraIjdbwmfNP7txrXBSsgRLY2e2QAik88QMxO2WysbDpR3vMqsot1eSweGN9NmezwY/oUwSXPR1SsZceUklMXEnQB5I4@Nhi/YLH1ClVcLoliEXI4HdR3v3XlMVakkNXjnnLLw)

That turned out long...

Straightforward approach:

1. Create all pairs of values from input list (leading zeros to fix issues with 1-length inputs). `unique` and `sort` take care of the "first element is smaller" requirement.
2. Define a helper function `+` to look for a value in nested list.
3. Which pairs are dependent? (Uses \$\lnot p \lor q\$ for implication.) Extract first elements from them.
4. `setdiff` those from all sublists.

Comment: sort unique is very clever

Comment: trivial 2 byte reduction by shoving `s` and `b` into function arguments and removing the `{}`

Comment: @Giuseppe, thanks - that was a leftover from previous attempts.

Comment: Do you need both of the leading zeros?  It [seems to work](https://tio.run/##bY3dDoIwDIXvfQr0qg29YOqVZk8CJLDJ4sLclI0EE98dh78J2ov2NP3OaTcqPqreyqCdhYE89/X5bK4kuHQnYUFCRt51AXqrL30Th9E@wICxaI1oHvjkbMJBK0UiZ@SB7ax0BgTSJ1xTlVb8s7boo@tUB3mkgYu8JV1ShlgbA8uU3dIYXuKo4PFPAqM1bZGeYjOJaSAm@0TWAVauD7skzyNUUuybVy8LW9gVLr45vx72h8r@YNmcmyPv83gH) with 1-length inputs with only one of them...

Comment: ...and possibly you could use ```apply``` instead of ```sapply(1:ncol())```, [like this](https://tio.run/##bU9BboMwELz3FTSnXbGHrElySMRLCFLAjRUUx6TBSCD179TGqS@uD7Nja2fG81pUuajRSNv1BiZqS9k/WgMStjT0Lwuj6b7Hqxu6GyxM6A4JRN08n3p2guFqvzqlqK2YwltLgqLjTJf8UsbrHYc/4aOx8kZTOVf3mraIjdbwmfNP7txrXBSsgRLY2e2QAik88QMxO2WysbDpR3vMqsot1eSweGN9NmezwY/oUwSXPR1SsZceUklMXEnQB5I4@Nhi/YLH1ClVcLoliEXI4HdR3v3XlMVakkNXjnnLLw)...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen, thanks. The second zero was a leftover from some previous attempt. And thanks for the `apply` - that's clever, but it's what `apply` is for after all.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>80</s> 70 bytes

```
f l=filter(\n->all(\m->m<=n||any((&&).elem n<*>all(/=m))l)$l>>=id)<$>l
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##NYxBDsIgEEWvMgvSgKEaWnUFXISyIJFG4kCa2o1J745IcfNfZt7Pf7r3yyPmPAOqOeDmVzqlXjtEOsVeR6nSvrv0obTr2Nmjj5DkqfqLiowhI6i1Cg8micYcXUigYFlD2oBAdAvMYIwRfOBXyyvHwl9a4EWN9X/j93b/G5XVHWy2ceBiqEoca6IUbP4C)

-10 bytes thanks to Wheat Wizard

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxBDsIgEEWvMgvSgKEaWnUFXISyIJFG4kCa2o1J745IcfNfZt7Pf7r3yyPmPAOqOeDmVzqlXjtEOsVeR6nSvrv0obTr2Nmjj5DkqfqLiowhI6i1Cg8micYcXUigYFlD2oBAdAvMYIwRfOBXyyvHwl9a4EWN9X/j93b/G5XVHWy2ceBiqEoca6IUbP4C "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>14</s> 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
εʒδåÏ.«Ãy›O_
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3NZTk85tObz0cL/eodWHmysfNezyj///PzraUMdIxyRWB0wbA2kQGQsA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifnFiiYKeQnJ@SqpdfnJiUmapgY6Pg6u/GZa@k8KhtkoKS/f9zW09NOrfl8NLD/XqHVh9urnzUsMs//n9trQ4XSB1XeUZmTqpCUWpiikJmHldKPpeCgn5@QYk@xDgohWaDjYIKWG1e6v/oaEMdIx2TWB0wbQykQWQsV3S0MVjUVMcMzIPJgmmwDIQGy4FJIx1DI7CwIcQUQ5AkAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
ε            # Map over each inner list of the (implicit) input list of lists:
 ʒ           #  Filter this inner list by:
  δ          #   Map over each list of the (implicit) input list of lists:
   å         #    Check if it contains the current integer
    Ï        #   Only keep those lists from the (implicit) input list of lists
     .«      #   Reduce the remaining list of lists by:
       Ã     #    Keep the values which are present in both lists
        y›   #   Then check which remaining values are larger than the current integer
          O  #   Sum to get the amount of values for which this is truthy
           _ #   Check if this sum is 0
             # (after which the modified list of lists is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 62 bytes

```
#/.Table[#⋂##&@@#~Select~MemberQ@ii||i->Set@$,{i,Max@#}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X1lfLyQxKSc1WvlRd5OyspqDg3JdcGpOanJJnW9qblJqUaBD5vsJ2zNrajJ17YJTSxxUdKozdXwTKxyUa2PV/geWZgLFAooy80qilXXt0hyUY9XqgpMT8@qquaqrDXWMdExqdcC0MZAGkbU6QAljsLCpjhmEC5MH02ApCA2RhFBGOoZGYAlDiEmGYGmwPBYLoIIwIa7a/wA)

The private-use character is [`\[VectorLessEqual]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorLessEqual.html).

```
   Table[                                     ,{i,Max@#}]   for positive i up to the max
#/.                                   i->Set@$              remove i if
         #⋂##&@@                                              intersection of
                #~Select~MemberQ@i                              lists containing i
                                  i||                        not all <=i
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 79 bytes

Expects an array of sets.

```javascript
a=>a.map(([...b])=>b.filter(p=>!b.some(q=>q>p&a.every(b=>b.has(q)|!b.has(p)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZA9bsMwDIV3n0JZChpQGchpsxTS1hNkNDxQrtwkcCz5BwkK9O6uRSVtA4SDKPB970ngkc401sMhTM@d/3Bzo2fShvBEAaBERFvl2lhsDu3kBgjarCyO/uSg16Y34YnQnd3wBTZSexqhz79X6RbyWPNbmQlRlkoW8qWS3DdLj2clBdd6vQBJ/ieybcPTV7n9hf@KbVHeXuFbNvdb3NKjleEoJoHHyfQg@e4FdQULqQqOVOmLakm4Ax8BWZVh44d3qvdAQhtR@270rcPWf0IDadM2Cp27iJ2bwKa1/QA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 85 bytes

```ruby
->l{l.map{|a|a-l.flatten.select{|x|l.select{|c|c&[x]!=[]}.reduce(&:&).any?{|y|y>x}}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6nOkcvN7GguiaxJlE3Ry8tJ7GkJDVPrzg1JzW5pLqmoiYHzk6uSVaLrohVtI2OrdUrSk0pTU7VULNS09RLzKu0r66prKm0q6gFgv8FCmnR0dGGOkY6JrE6YNoYSIPI2FguiKQxWMpUxwwo9B8A)